# how to redirect to the same route (from where the request came) in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm posting a form from a partial view which is rendered via `Html.RenderAction` and I want after the form post to redirect to the same route from where the request came.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return PartialView();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormModel input)
{
     ...
     return //Redirect to the same route
}
```

anybody knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could retrieve the UrlReferrer from the Request object:

```
return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString);
```

Comment: it works, but we loose the values that were in the forms, they aren't sent back

Comment: Add the form data to the TempData. You can then retrieve this after the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a query string to the the form post, which you can use to do the redirection in the controller action.

```
<form action="example.com/model/edit?returnurl=http://example.com/Form" method="post">
```

Controller action...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormModel input, string returnUrl)
{
     ...
     return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```